# Windows Service ConnectionString property has not been initialized?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-services, csla

I am attempting to use a windows service to run at midnight every day and then checks a SQL table to see if any dates of future transactions match today's date. It is then supposed to fetch those records as objects and sends them off to another service for processing. However before I have even gotten to this step I am getting some strange errors from the windows service in my error log that I'm not sure how to properly debug or narrow down what is happening.

At first I was just getting a generic Type Initializer error with the classes that I was calling upon in the windows service until I changed my error logging to include the inner exception and now it looks like an issue initializing the connectionString even though I have called on the connection string directly within my Windows service now.

I am unsure as to why it would be having connection string issues when I'm creating a new SQLConnection with the plaintext connection string, is there some kind of translation error going on between my Windows Service and the rest of my solution?

Here is my Windows Service Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Afi.BusinessObjects.Billing
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Service1

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.

    Dim PaymentsToBeProcessed As New FuturePaymentsCollection


    Me.WriteToFile("Future Transaction Processor started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))

    Try

        PaymentsToBeProcessed = GetFutureTransactionsByDate(DateTime.Now.Date)

        Dim ProcessedPaymentsString As String = String.Format("{0} payments were processed during this session.", PaymentsToBeProcessed.Count)

        Me.WriteToFile(ProcessedPaymentsString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then

            WriteToFile("Future Transaction Processing Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException.ToString())
        Else

            'Log any errors we get.
            WriteToFile("Future Transaction Processing Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)

        End If

    End Try

    Me.ScheduleService()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    Me.WriteToFile("Future Transaction Processor stopped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
    Me.Schedular.Dispose()
End Sub

Protected mFuturePayment As AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment
Public Property Payment() As AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment
    Get
        Return mFuturePayment
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment)
        mFuturePayment = value

    End Set
End Property

Private Schedular As Timer

Public Sub ScheduleService()
    Try

        'Initialize a new Timer called Schedular and give it the callback of SchedularCallback
        Schedular = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf SchedularCallback))

        'Set our run mode as daily, so the service will run itself every day. 
        Dim runMode As String = "DAILY"


        'Sets scheduledTime to a DateTime value
        Dim scheduledTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue


        If runMode = "DAILY" Then

            'Gets our scheduled time from the app settings if the mode is equal to Daily and sets it equal to ScheduledTime
            scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse("09:20")

            'If the time has already been passed then we'll schedule our service to run for tomorrow at the same time previously set.
            If DateTime.Now > scheduledTime Then
                scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1)

            End If
        End If

        'Gets the difference in time between now and the scheduled time for the service to run.
        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

        'Creates a string of our timeSpan to the next time the service should run.
        Dim schedule As String = String.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds)

        'Prints our next scheduled run to our log file.
        Me.WriteToFile((Convert.ToString("Future Transaction Processor scheduled to run after: ") & schedule) + " {0}")

        'Get the difference in milliseconds between the Scheduled and Current Time.
        Dim dueTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds)

        'Change the Timer's Due Time
        Schedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite)

        'If there are any errors write them to the log. 
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToFile("Future Transaction Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)

        'Stop the Windows Service
        Using serviceController As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("FutureTransactionProcessor")
            serviceController.[Stop]()
        End Using
    End Try
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetFutureTransactionsByDate(ByVal dateToday As DateTime) As FuturePaymentsCollection

    Dim FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed As FuturePaymentsCollection = New FuturePaymentsCollection

        Using cnSQL As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=rdbashq01;Database=AFI_SYSTEM;User ID=*****;Password=****;Trusted_Connection=False;")

            Using cmdSP As New SqlCommand("PROC_FUTURE_TRANSACTIONS_SEL_BY_TODAY", cnSQL)

                cmdSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmdSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATETODAY", dateToday)

                cmdSP.Connection.Open()
                Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = cmdSP.ExecuteReader()

                If sqlReader.HasRows Then
                    While (sqlReader.Read())
                        Dim futurePayment As New FuturePayment

                        futurePayment.FutureTransactionID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_ID"))
                        futurePayment.GroupID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_CNTC_GROUP_ID"))
                        futurePayment.PayorAccountID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_PAYOR_ACCOUNT_ID"))
                        futurePayment.PolicyID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_POLICY_ID"))
                        futurePayment.AccountTypeID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID"))
                        futurePayment.TransationTypeID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID"))
                        futurePayment.TransactionDate = sqlReader.GetDateTime(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_DATE")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        futurePayment.TransactionSubmitter = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_SUBMITTER"))
                        futurePayment.TransactionAmount = sqlReader.GetDecimal(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"))
                        futurePayment.TransactionLast4 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_LAST4"))
                        futurePayment.TransactionEmail = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_EMAIL"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo1 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo1"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo2 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo2"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo3 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo3"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo4 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo4"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo5 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo5"))
                        futurePayment.PaymentInfo6 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo6"))
                        futurePayment.TransactionUpdateDate = sqlReader.GetDateTime(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_UPDATE_DATE"))

                        FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed.Add(futurePayment)

                    End While
                End If

            cmdSP.Connection.Close()

            End Using

    End Using

        For Each Payment As FuturePayment In FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed

            Dim PaymentToBeProcessed As OneTimePayment

            PaymentToBeProcessed.PayorAccountId = Payment.PayorAccountID
            PaymentToBeProcessed.PolicyID = Payment.PolicyID
            PaymentToBeProcessed.AccountTypeID = Payment.AccountTypeID

            PaymentToBeProcessed.PayTypeID = 1
            PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoName = Payment.PaymentInfo1
            PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoRoutingNum = Payment.PaymentInfo2
            PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum = Payment.PaymentInfo3

            If PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum >= 4 Then
                PaymentToBeProcessed.Last4 = PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum.Substring(PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum.Length - 4, 4)
            Else
                PaymentToBeProcessed.Last4 = "XXXX"
            End If

            PaymentToBeProcessed.TransactionTypeID = 1
            PaymentToBeProcessed.Email = Payment.TransactionEmail
            PaymentToBeProcessed.TransactionAmount = Payment.TransactionAmount


            PaymentToBeProcessed.Save()
            PaymentToBeProcessed.SendPaymentToGateway()

            'Run our method to remove the future payment from the Future_Transactions table and enter it into the Future_transactions_History table as processed
        Payment.ProcessFuturePayment(Payment.FutureTransactionID)

        Next

        Return FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed

End Function



Private Sub SchedularCallback(e As Object)
    Me.WriteToFile("Future Transaction Log: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
    Me.ScheduleService()

End Sub


Private Sub WriteToFile(text As String)
    Dim path As String = "C:\FutureTransactionLog.txt"
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(path, True)
        writer.WriteLine(String.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")))
        writer.Close()
    End Using

End Sub

End Class
```

The following below is my stack trace...I believe that my issue is  the csla.DataPortalException: DataPortal.Fetc failed (System.InvalidOperationException: the ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)

```
Future Transaction Processor stopped at 12/10/2015 10:49:23 AM
Future Transaction Processor started at 12/10/2015 10:49:46 AM
Future Transaction Processing Error on: 12/10/2015 10:49:46 AM The type       initializer for 'AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment' threw an exception.   at AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment..ctor()

at FutureTransactionProcessor.Service1.GetFutureTransactionsByDate(DateTime dateToday) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\FutureTransactionProcessor\Service1.vb:line 159

at FutureTransactionProcessor.Service1.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\FutureTransactionProcessor\Service1.vb:line 27Csla.DataPortalException: DataPortal.Fetch failed (System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Afi.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteQuery(String Query) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Data\ConnectionManager.vb:line 20

at Afi.Configuration.SystemSetting.SystemSettingsCollection.DataPortal_Fetch(Object v_Criteria) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Configuration\SystemSettings.vb:line 169) ---> Csla.Server.CallMethodException: DataPortal_Fetch method call failed ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

 at Afi.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteQuery(String Query) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Data\ConnectionManager.vb:line 20

  at Afi.Configuration.SystemSetting.SystemSettingsCollection.DataPortal_Fetch(Object v_Criteria) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Configuration\SystemSettings.vb:line 169

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Afi.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteQuery(String Query) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Data\ConnectionManager.vb:line 20

at Afi.Configuration.SystemSetting.SystemSettingsCollection.DataPortal_Fetch(Object v_Criteria) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Configuration\SystemSettings.vb:line 169

at Csla.MethodCaller.CallMethod(Object obj, MethodInfo info, Object[] parameters)

at Csla.Server.SimpleDataPortal.Fetch(Type objectType, Object criteria, DataPortalContext context)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Afi.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteQuery(String Query) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Data\ConnectionManager.vb:line 20

 at Afi.Configuration.SystemSetting.SystemSettingsCollection.DataPortal_Fetch(Object v_Criteria) in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Configuration\SystemSettings.vb:line 169

at Csla.MethodCaller.CallMethod(Object obj, MethodInfo info, Object[] parameters)

at Csla.Server.SimpleDataPortal.Fetch(Type objectType, Object criteria, DataPortalContext context)

at Csla.DataPortal.Fetch(Type objectType, Object criteria)

at Csla.DataPortal.Fetch[T](Object criteria)

at Afi.Configuration.SystemSetting.get_Collection() in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Configuration\SystemSettings.vb:line 97

at Afi.Security.SecSystem.get_Collection() in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Security\SecSystem.vb:line 127

at Afi.Security.AFISecurityIdentifier.LoadObjects() in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI\Security\AFISecurityIdentifier.vb:line 21

at AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing.FuturePayment..cctor() in C:\TFS ITD\Console\Main\Source\AFI_BusinessObjects\Billing\FuturePayment.vb:line 26
```

If I am understanding this correctly the project can't create my connection string to fetch the data from SQL? Could someone please help me understand more about what is going on or help me narrow down where to troubleshoot this? It's also been suggested to me by one of our more senior devs that maybe I need to just use the Windows Service to trigger the methods and put all these methods into a Web Service instead...would that fix all of these issues, or should they be working within a windows service?

I can provide more information in comments below if anyone has questions to help me pinpoint my issue, thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Below is the constructor for FuturePayment

```
#Region "  Constructors  "

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


#End Region
```

Comment: Why is your connection string hard coded in the middle of your code? It should be in your config file. What line is the exception happening on?

Comment: Hi Sean, I've tried to add a config file with it dynamically going to that as well but I get all the same errors when I place it in app.config under the windows service. 

The exception is happening on this line:  futurePayment.FutureTransactionID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_ID"))

Comment: Are you sure ? This line: Dim futurePayment As New FuturePayment only looks suspicious for me. What is in FuturePayment constructor ?

Comment: It's just a default constructor, I've edited my post and added the constructor to the bottom. All of the properties for FuturePayment are public as well.

Comment: Someone has similar problem here (looking on exception) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129479/connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized and answers probably helps him. Maybe try to not use using statemant for testing it.

Comment: I am testing this windows service on my local machine and not our server. I wonder if that is the problem with establishing a connection to fetch the data from the SQL server.

Comment: The first line of the exception stack trace indicates to me that the type has an initializer (shared sub new in VB). You really need to look at that code to see if it creates a new SqlConnection and tries to Open it before setting the connection string.

Comment: when you are stepping through your code, what is the connection state at each line after you call `cmdSP.Connection.Open()`? Does it ever actually make it to `Open`?

Comment: Hey Mike, I can't use break points because it is in a windows service...or if I can then I'm ignorant as to how to do that, I have to log any errors I get and troubleshoot after.

Comment: Ok, you can debug windows services but doing it is a bit tricky. and the process is a little long for a comment so I will submit an answer with the steps for you.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug a windows service:

Before we compile and install the service you will want to add some code to your `OnStart` handler. The idea is that we will write a method that basically puts the thread to sleep and gives us time to attach the debugger. I normally add a sub procedure to the service class and call it WaitForDebugging or something to that effect. Your method should look something like:

```
Private Sub WaitForDebugging()
    #If DEBUG Then
        Dim timeout = Now.AddSeconds(30)
        Dim x As Boolean = True
        While Now < timeout And x
            'Set x to false while debugging to jump out of this early'
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        End While
    #End If
End Sub
```

The `#if DEBUG then` clause is to protect this from being run in production. You will want to set a breakpoint on the `While Now < timeout And x` line for later.

The first thing your `OnStart` handler should do is call the `WaitForDebugging` method.

So with that in place you are ready to compile and install your windows service like normal. Once the service is installed simply start it as you normally would.

Here is where things will get a bit different than you are used to. Instead of your service starting quickly, the progress bar will appear to hang, this is completely fine and expected. What you need to do is have your solution open in VS when you are starting your service. Once you start your service immediately switch to VS (even before the progress bar has hung) and then go to `Tools -> Attach to Process`. If you are using the default key combination setup for VB.NET then using `Ctrl + Alt + P` will get you to the same interface.

The Attach to Process interface will look like:

[image]

Make sure that the blue highlighted check box is checked in your interface. Once that is done search the list for the name of your service. Once you find your service simply select it in the list and click the `Attach` button. VS will go through some stuff and once its finished the program should break at the breakpoint we set up earlier.

Then you can either set `x` to false to kick out early or wait the 30 seconds and step through your code like normal.

And there you have it. Following those steps you should be able to debug through any windows service you create.